# Ошибка: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. 
Прошу сильно не пинайте.
Начал изучать Java. И вот дошел до Схем размещения. С GridLayout, BorderLayout вроде разобрался и все у меня работает. Но вот с BoxLayout что то не получается. Сама IDE никаких ошибок не выдает, а при запуске проекта выдает ошибку:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at calculator.Calculator.setLayout(Calculator.java:11)
    at calculator.Calculator.<init>(Calculator.java:57)
    at calculator.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:86)
Java Result: 1
```

Вот сам текст программы:

package calculator;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

public class Calculator {

```
private void setLayout(BoxLayout boxLayout) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

JButton button1;
JButton button2;
JButton button3;
JButton button4;
JButton button5;
JButton button6;
JButton button7;
JButton button8;
JButton button9;
JButton button0;
JButton buttonPoint;
JButton buttonEqual;
JPanel windowContent;
JTextField displayField;
JPanel p1;

Calculator() {

    windowContent = new JPanel();

    BorderLayout b1 = new BorderLayout();
    windowContent.setLayout(b1);

    displayField = new JTextField(30);
    windowContent.add("North", displayField);

    button1 = new JButton("1");
    button2 = new JButton("2");
    button3 = new JButton("3");
    button4 = new JButton("4");
    button5 = new JButton("5");
    button6 = new JButton("6");
    button7 = new JButton("7");
    button8 = new JButton("8");
    button9 = new JButton("9");
    button0 = new JButton("0");
    buttonPoint = new JButton(".");
    buttonEqual = new JButton("=");

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    p1.add(button1);
    p1.add(button2);
    p1.add(button3);
    p1.add(button4);
    p1.add(button5);
    p1.add(button6);
    p1.add(button7);
    p1.add(button8);
    p1.add(button9);
    p1.add(button0);
    p1.add(buttonPoint);
    p1.add(buttonEqual);

    windowContent.add("Center", p1);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Калькулятор");
    frame.setContentPane(windowContent);

    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы определили метод, единственным действием которого является выбрасывание ошибки:

```
private void setLayout(BoxLayout boxLayout) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

и вызываете его:

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Чтобы избавиться от этой ошибки достаточно закомментировать вызов:

```
//throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.
А если не трудно, можете подсказать, почему ругается на строку p1.add(button1);?

Comment: @kirasirrr Каким образом ругается? Добавьте данные об ошибке к вашему вопросу.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я уже разобрался.